# Update component org.json:json

Tags: activemq-artemis

Good day!
Can you tell me how update the org.json:json component to a newer version? Current version - 20171018. Newer version - 20220924.

Comment: As far as I understand, the component is part of hawtio-war, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's 100% backwards compatible you can just download the new jar (e.g. from [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.json/json/20220924/bundle)) and replace the old one with the new one in the broker distribution.

In ActiveMQ Artemis 2.27.1 `json-20171018.jar` is in the `<ARTEMIS_HOME>/web/console.war` archive in the `/WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: I couldn't find the jar file to replace. That's the problem, it's nowhere to be found. As I wrote in the comment above - I suspect that it is part of hawtio-war.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you running?

Comment: ActiveMQ Artemis version - 2.27.1

Comment: I updated my answer to provide the location of `json-20171018.jar`.

Comment: As an update: Artemis 2.31.0 version is out and org.json:json is upgraded to version 20230227.